# How to fire FB::MouseEnteredEvent and FB::MouseExitedEvent?

Tags: c++, firebreath

I am creating a plugin using Firebreath, I am trying to fire `FB::MouseEnteredEvent` and `FB::MouseExitedEvent` as per given in http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class+FB+MouseEvent

but still not getting the events. Also in `PluginWindowWin.cpp` file there is no `WM` message for `MouseEntered` and `MouseExited`. So how to find out the way to trap the mouse enter and mouse leave message in firebreath.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Which browser are you on?

Comment: I want do on every browser but currently I am using IE